# How to limit bandwidth of a specific app (iTunes)

Tags: itunes, safari, internet

I'm currently downloading another series of 24, and I'm also downloading photoshop cs6 beta in Safari. iTunes is steadily downloading 24, several episodes ahead of where I'm watching, but photoshop CS6 is downloading much slower (if I pause 24, then it speeds up significantly)

Given that it's downloading several episodes ahead, I would like to slow down iTunes so that Safari can download CS6 faster. (but not pause iTunes because it's getting close to peak times when my connection is throttled, so it's best to use as much data as possible beforehand)

Is there a built in feature of OSX or iTunes that lets you allocate bandwidth to apps?
Or is there a 3rd party app that allows you to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This utility allows you to throttle speeds on certain domains -  http://osxdaily.com/2009/08/19/limit-connection-bandwidth-with-speedlimit/

You could then throttle the domains that iTunes uses - `a1.phobos.apple.com` to `a1999.phobos.apple.com`